# Is my data suited for an ANOVA?

Tags: anova, gamma-distribution

I have two types of "media" (surface and sediment). I have six toxin variants "variant". All the toxins originate in the surface water, but I want to know if certain toxins are more likely to accumulate in the sediment. So the question I'm trying to answer: are there significant differences in toxin presence between sediment and water? and are there significant differences in toxin presence between sediment and water based on the variant type?

Should I run 6 one way ANOVAs?  Or a two way ANOVA?

Also the data follows a gamma distribution-which makes me wonder if I should be using a different test than an ANOVA (assuming ANOVA was the correct approach if data was normal).

This is just a sample of my data below.

[image]

Comment: This looks like two way ANOVA, can you make a 2x2 table of your data?

Comment: Can you post (a link to) your data, that is, not only as an image?

Comment: You could also try a gamma glm (generalized linear model)